# Cбои андроид приложения java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Несколько сбоев было но не могу понять изза чего. Взгляните:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw (DisplayListCanvas.java:260)

  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1420)

  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw (BitmapDrawable.java:545)

  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw (ImageView.java:1286)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18318)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild (RecyclerView.java:4581)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)

  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw (RecyclerView.java:3987)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:1229)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:1229)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild (DrawerLayout.java:1366)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17291)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18080)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3966)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3752)

  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:18321)

  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:919)

  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:17296)

  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:692)

  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:698)

  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:806)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3128)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2924)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2516)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1515)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7091)

  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)

  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)

  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:638)

  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:913)

  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

что это может быть?

Comment: посмотри, есть ли предупреждения в xml, если да, то попробуй убрать, и обрати внимание на версию android.

Comment: версия андроид на котором произошла ошибка 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Если верить исходникам Андроида при отрисовке картинки эту ошибку могут вызватьтри причины:

> "Canvas: trying to draw too large(" + bitmapSize + "bytes) bitmap."

Битмап (раскодированный) больше 100МБ

> "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap "

Битмап был помечен для удаления

> "Canvas: trying to use a non-premultiplied bitmap "

У битмапа не подготовлен альфа-канал

Судя по стэку у Вас, похоже, первый вариант